# about WifiManager.bundle

Tags: iphone, ipod

What will be the result of the

```
libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/WiFiManager.bundle/WiFiManager", RTLD_LAZY);
```

I'm using this for getting wifi info on ipod os 3.1.2., because when I `NSLog(@"Result %@",libhandle);` I'm getting null what should be the answer,

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this discussion](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/issues/detail?id=26#c11), doing the above will return NULL on the iPhone Simulator, because it lacks the required bundle.  If you are still running into issues with this on the device, it might be that Apple has changed the internal file structure for that system item.  This is one of the reasons why it is bad to rely in private APIs.

For more on WiFi snooping, you might refer to the source code for [this project](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Stumbler), because they might have resolved these issues.  However, once again I'd like to remind you that you will not be able to submit an application to the App Store that uses this, because of the private API calls.  Apple is now scanning all submitted applications for these calls and instantly rejecting them.